# Unable to find x64 version of MFC 9.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to build a legacy project written for Visual Studio 2008 using x64. Everything goes well until the linker fails with the line:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'nafxcwd.lib'

This file exists in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib but that's the 32 bit version. I have a 64 bit version in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64 but that's the wrong version of MFC and introduces other errors. Is there anywhere I can download the 64 bit version of MFC 9.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS2008 there must be also a subfolder amd64 in the Lib folder.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\amd64"

If this folder is not existing you may not installed the 64bit tools and libraries. Start the setup of VS2008 again and change your configuration.
There is no legal source to download this files.

Comment: I have this directory but there's no nafxcwd.lib file in it.

Comment: So just run the Setup again as I wrote!

Comment: I tried running the installer from disk but it failed. I had to run it from Control Panel->Programs and Features->Uninstall/Change with the original installation disk inserted.